# Issue casting to custom class

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, icarousel

I am using [these](https://github.com/piemonte/Player) two [libraries](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel).

My goal here is to get a player into each cell of the carousel view. So far I have just been following the example in the `iCarousel` repo.

If you look at the example in the [git](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel/blob/master/Examples/Swift%20Example/SwiftExample/ViewController.swift) repository, you will see that the cell is created and then referenced to.

to reference the player in the reused view I am trying

```
let player: Player
    if view == nil {
       player = Player()
       //Do stuff with player
    } else {
       player = view.viewWithTag(1) as! Player
    }
```

but I get the error: Cast from `UIView` to unrelated type **'Player'** always fails

any help is appreciated

Comment: A `Player` is a UIViewController, not a UIView.

Comment: I failed to mention that I tried casting to UIViewController also.. I get "Cannot assign value of type 'UIViewController' to type Player

Answer (score 1):

The call to `view.viewWithTag(1)` returns a `UIView` but `Player` is a subclass of `UIViewController` which are not related, so you cannot cast from one to another. You need `UIView`s for the carousel so you cannot use the `Player` class.